# Merging two queries into one using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this two queries to display information in 3 tables Users, Comments, and Posts. so I made this function:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $posts = Post::with(['comments'])->findOrFail($id);
        $user = User::find($posts->user_id);

        echo "<h1>".$posts->title.'</h1>';
        echo "<h2>".$user->name.'</h2>';

        foreach ($posts->comments as $comment) {
            echo $comment->body.'<br>';
        }
    }
```

on this function I using two variable $posts and $user, can I merge this two variable using eloquests command like Post::with(['user','comments'])'? so I can use just $posts variable and use it like $posts->users->name to access user name.

i was trying using this way:

```
$posts = Post::with(['comments','users'])->findOrFail($id);
```

but when i echo the post it showing that the user was null:

```
{"id":1,"user_id":1,"title":"Oleh id 1","body":"ini adalah content","created_at":"2017-10-18 03:25:54","updated_at":"2017-10-18 03:25:54","comments":[{"id":1,"post_id":1,"body":"Keren banget deh artikelnya, TOP","created_at":"2017-10-18 03:43:50","updated_at":"2017-10-18 03:43:50"},{"id":2,"post_id":1,"body":"Keren banget deh artikelnya, TOP","created_at":"2017-10-18 03:43:53","updated_at":"2017-10-18 03:43:53"},{"id":3,"post_id":1,"body":"Keren banget deh artikelnya, TOP","created_at":"2017-10-18 03:43:54","updated_at":"2017-10-18 03:43:54"}],"users":null}
```

Here's my model if you need it. My post model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

my Comment model

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the post that owns the comment.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `array_merge` for this. Do like: `$allData = array_merge($posts->toArray(), $user->toArray());` Then see the result of `$allData`.

Comment: @HirenGohel is it no eloquent command for it?

Comment: Try `$allData = $posts->toBase()->merge($user->toBase());`

Comment: @HirenGohel it means I have to use two queries, for getting all posts and users right? there is no way i can use syntax like Post::with([úser,'comments'])'?

Comment: You asked about merge, not using eloquent in your question!

Comment: @HirenGohel sorry for it, I updated my question already.

Comment: You will need to loop on `$posts` to get the users for each post

Comment: Have you defined relationships in your models?

Comment: @baig772 not sure what happen but echo my posts and I got "null" on users.

Comment: @HirenGohel yes, I already defined. the code above is work, I just don't know is it possible to get the same result by using 1 queries without having to search the users first.

Comment: Try `$comments = $post->comments()->with('user')->get();` Then see the `dd` result of `$comments`

Comment: @HirenGohel i don't have any problem accessing the comment, but i can't get the data from Users table. and that $user->name was the name of the user that make Post.

Comment: @Henra Please see my answer! I have defined `$comments = $post->comments()->with('user')->get();` this means it gives you user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days searching finally i got the answer, i can get merge the query like this:

```
$posts = Post::with(['comments','users'])->findOrFail($id);
```

but in the Post Model the function not "Users" but "User".

Answer (score 0):

What I am guessing is you want the list of all posts with the users. If relation is defined, try with the `join`

```
$posts   =   DB::table('posts')
             ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
             ->select('posts.*', 'users.name as user_name')
             ->where('posts.comments', '<>', NULL)
             ->get();
```

@NOTE: If you are using `soft deletes` you might wanna add `where('posts.deleted_at', null)`

Comment: there is no way i can use with Eloquent? oh with your code i got this errors "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'"

Comment: try now. removed the extra `,`

Comment: got an errors "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts.comments' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `posts`.*, `users`.`name` as `user_name` from `posts` inn ▶"

Comment: Well the error is quite clear, there isn't any column named `comments` in posts table. What is the relation of posts and comments?

Answer (score 0):

You’ll have an easier time sticking to Laravel’s conventions for naming relationships.

A `Post` has many `Comments`, which belong to a `User`. Given this set up:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
   public function post()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
   }

   public function user()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
}
```

You can then query a post’s comments and users like this:

```
$comments = $post->comments()->with('user')->get();
```

You could also eager-load the `user` relation on `comments` if you always wanted the user returned with a comment:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['user'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Then your query would be simplified:

```
$comments = $post->comments;
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: thanks, but all I want is get the user name who created the post. not the user who makes the comment.

Comment: Then do `$user = User::find($id);
    $posts = $user->posts()->get();` This gives you user name who created the post.

Comment: it gives me an errors "Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance." but is it by this way i can access into comment tables either?

Comment: See, in `$user = User::find($id);` $id is Auth user id and this gives you user collection, then you can access users info whatever you want!

Comment: but that auth require users to login right? all i want is display whose the name of a user that write the post and show all comments in the articles.

Comment: No, it's not required user login. You can get id from posts table also

Comment: well yes i already get the user_id from the routes, i just confuse since i can't get the comment and the user info directly just using one query. i though i can use Post::with('user','comment') but i can't. it gives null for the user. but the comments and post work just fine.

Comment: Ok, then do as i said before, the solution is merge if you want! Or you need to take one more table named as `posts_user` and this gives you user info with posts!

Comment: Ok, I will use your suggestion later if I can't find any other ways. by the way, I update my question maybe it will make it clearer.

Comment: Try last time to define this in your `post` model: `public function users()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(post::class);
   }` Add this relation in your post model only. I think this should works!

Comment: i already add like this:  public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
} it's a same right?

Comment: ups sorry, but why post class?

Comment: yes i change already like u said, but it give me same errors like i write in my question. the users data still null. do you want me to write all model that i use?

Comment: u make me confuse since i just follow what written in elqouent documentation. it written like this: class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the post that owns the comment.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }

Comment: i still can't fix it yet. i already try your way, but still, doesn't work.